# 2sxc Blog App - Tag View

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I'm using the blog app and I created a new Pipeline to give me all posts so that I could create a view that would show the archive of posts. I have it working as expected.

On my DNN page, i put another App module on the page and set the view to show the archives list and it works well on the main list view of the Blog App. When I click on a year, say 2016 to see all the posts for that year, the list view  shows the correct list of posts based on the PublicationMoment attribute. The problem I'm running into is that It also changes the View on the App module that I had set to show the archives and I think it's because the Blog App as a whole is setup to change the views based on the query string parameters and both of the Blog Apps are changed to show the list of posts. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution. I created another app and set that app to pull the data from the main blog app so that the view that was displaying the Archive lost was independent of the main blog app and subsequently the view for that app didn't change with the query string parameters.